# How to duplicate a string 10 times

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I have a prompt that asks the user to enter one word and then I want to duplicate this word 10 times using a for loop and show the result in an alert box.

It's just I can't seem to figure out what I need to enter inside my for loop to get it to duplicate my message variable ten times and then save the result to another variable which I can show in my alert box. Does someone know how to do this in Javascript?

Edit: This is the code I tried now:

```
function button() {
    var message = prompt ("Enter a word", "");
    for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        message += message;
    }
    alert (message);
}
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: learn how to use a for loop in javascript;
learn how to assign data to variables in javascript;
learn how to concatenate two strings;
then probably learn how to effectively concatenate strings in javascript;
done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are a new user, I'll just mention that SO expects you to provide any and all code you have attempted thus far. We love to help but always expect you to show that you have tried to solve the issue on your own. We do not just write code for you.

Please give [this](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried) a read and welcome to StackOverflow!

```
var foo = 'test', out = '';

for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
  out += foo;
}

console.log(out); // 'testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest'
```

Edit:

```
var message = prompt("Enter a message", ""),
    newMessage = '';

for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
  newMessage += message;
}

alert(newMessage);
```

Comment: That does not "duplicate it 10 times". Replace 10 with 1024 to do that.

Comment: @Ingo this does what the OP asked.  It duplicates the input word 10 times, he didnt ask to duplicate duplicated string each time.

Comment: @Ingo the OP just changed the question on me!

Comment: NO, he said *duplicate my message variable ten times*, i.e. `for (1..10) message = duplicate(message)`

Comment: " I want to duplicate this word 10 times using a for loop and show the result in an alert box" duplicating the original message variable 10 times, not duplicating recursively(a for loop wouldnt be used in recursion)

Comment: @Kyle No Ingo made that edit to change the question.  OP hasnt responded and Ingo is misinterpreting the question

Comment: @jzworkman This is debatable, but why should one want to do this 10 times, when duplication of the original striung always returns the same value?

Comment: @Ingo why would he want to do it 1024 times then? Both requests seem absurd.

Comment: @jzworkman - Answer what he said, not what he meant, this way he will learn communication skills. BTW, if I asked you to triple a string 10 times, what would your answer be?

Comment: In any case, to duplicate the way @Ingo is interpreting, no need to use `1024`, just don't use an output var; Mutate `foo` directly: `foo += foo`

Comment: Sorry, I started with Javascript just 4 days ago. I will read the article! I have edited my original post with the code I tried now. But now it duplicates the string to many times, not 10 times.

Comment: @Kyle Must have done something wrong when I tried your solution the first time but now it works! Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

You can make an empty array the length+1 of your repeat size, and join the array with the string to be repeated as the delimeter.

```
var string='Hello ', n=10;
alert(Array(n+1).join(string));
```

returned value: (String)

Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello

Answer (score 4):

In ES6 it's super easy.

> `String.prototype.repeat(repetition_number)` works fine.

example:

> `'abc'.repeat(3) // abcabcabc`

For more info: [freecodecamp/ES6-repeat](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/three-ways-to-repeat-a-string-in-javascript-2a9053b93a2d/)